# Fieldset not resizing when inner content is resized

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
        .box
        {
            background-color:Gray;
            width:300px;
            height:400px;
            position:relative;
            padding-top : 50px;
            padding-bottom : 50px;
            padding-left : 50px;
            padding-right : 50px;
        }

        fieldset
        {
            border-color : Red;
            width : 50% !important;
            padding-top : 50px;
            padding-bottom : 50px;
            padding-left : 50px;
            padding-right : 50px;
        }
 </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#resizable").resizable();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset id="fdemo">
<div id="resizable" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" class='box'></div>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Attached above is the html code with a fieldset and a resizable div within the fieldset.

My user can resize the div to any width he wishes. In my real application I have other elements that resize. So this is just a relating demo.
In case my user resizes a control (in this case the div within the fieldset) to a width greater than the width of the fieldset, the width of the fieldset should increase so that the div is contained within the bounds of the fieldset.

When you execute the above code and put IE8 or IE9 in quirks mode, you will notice that the desired behaviour is achieved, the fieldset's width increases and the div is contained within the fieldset.

However when the document goes into standard mode(i.e. IE8 standard mode or IE9 standard mode), resizing of the div does not resize the fieldset. The fieldset stays as it is and the div moves over and out of the fieldset.

I am unable to understand why this is occuring and am not aware of availablity or unavailability of any property that could cause this issue to occur.

I need a solution that would allow the above to work on IE7, IE8 and IE9.
I understand that this is most probably a css related issue, so I would like a css solution that could be globally applied.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a jsfiddle to serve as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/Rwdck/1/

Testing in IE 9 Standards mode per the requirement.

I noted that `width : 50% !important;` kept the `fieldset` from resizing beyond a certain point (which makes sense). The width looks uneven because width is calculated as width + padding + border, so 50% is actually larger than 50% of the available area (unless `box-sizing` is set to `border-box`, which isn't supported in IE 7).

When I removed `width : 50% !important;`, the fieldset resized along with the box, but it starts at 100% width (since it is a block element) which I doubt is the desired behavior.

Regardless, I did not find a scenario in which the fieldset didn't logically resize (or not resize) along with its contents.

Here is an example where I have removed width constraints on the `fieldsets` and floated them: http://jsfiddle.net/Rwdck/5/

This may be closer to the desired behavior as it provides a fluid layout and the `fieldsets` resize as you would expect. I tested in IE 7/8/9 standards and the resizing works correctly. I did note a jQuery UI or JSFiddle script error in IE 7.

Here is another example which uses `display: inline-block` - http://jsfiddle.net/Rwdck/8/

Comment: I removed the "width:50% !important" and the fieldset was resizing in IE8. However, it still does not work on IE9.  I tried setting the float property but it did not help. Could you please provide me with the exact html/javascript/css code that made it work on IE9 standards for you.

Comment: See edit: the second fiddle works in IE 9 standards and the 3rd one (just added) also does. The first one works correctly in Chrome but not IE9.